# how to make multiple JSON request and combine them

Tags: ios, json, swift, object

I am very new to swift (just spent 1 day on it).
I recently want to convert my jquery web to an ios app.
my project is to get a number of JSON requests and combine them together.

```
class RemoteAPI{
class func getJSON(completionHandler: NSArray -> ()) {
    let jsonUrl = ["http://a.json","http://b.json","http://c.json","http://d.json"];
    var cjson: [AnyObject] = []

    for var i = 0 ; i < jsonUrl.count ; i++ {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let r = jsonUrl[i]
        let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: r)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
            cjson.append(jsonData)
            completionHandler(cjson)
        } catch _ {
        // Error
        }

        }

        task.resume()
    }


}
}
```

In class Viewcontroller, i put

```
RemoteAPI.getJSON() { (cjson) in
        print(cjson)
        }
```

But the output is d.json, d.json, b.json, d.json, b.json, c.json, d.json, b.json, c.json, a.json. Why is it not d,b,c,a.json but repeated? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in swift but with objective-c I'd use AFNetworking (3rd party API for networking) and create a serial queue which would process each request via FIFO and each JSON would be added to a dictionary. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. But that sounds a bit complicated. I finally discovered that the cjson was actually printed 4 times (I discovered by using NSLog to see the timestamp) because completeHandler inside the loop was functioned for 4 times. Therefore, I added a counter and only do completeHandler until the counter reached the last count. I am still open to any other better answer/approach to this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually my suggestion is quite common for iOS developers - you simply use the iOS framework. Good luck.